# Notification Widget required to add APP Groups

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, widget, ios8

I have developing one app with Notification widget. but having issue with APP Groups (which is in app Targets --> capabilities). how to add entitlements in it.? having issue when add App Groups. [image]

I have checked many links for notification widget. but not getting proper guidance & having some queries. Anyone have its proper doc or example?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to search for "Today widget". The official documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html)

If you add App Groups in Xcode the entitlements file should be automatically added.

Comment: i want to know that to add app Groups is necessary?. cause having issue when i have add App Groups in my App.

Comment: It is. What issues do you have? That screenshot is perfectly normal and you should press "Request".

Comment: yes i have do that. but from where i have to accept that request? that i don't know.

Comment: i have checked in my app its not necessary to add App Group while integrating Widgets. @kevin thanks for your help.

Comment: Hey, I learned something new then too, good to know. Mind marking my answer as correct if it helped pointing this out?

Comment: which new thing you have learn on this Widget. just share here so i can get more help from that.

Comment: That it is not necessary. I did think it was :-)